# how to handle foursquare api's sensitivity with lat, lng

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, foursquare

In foursquare api explore, it automatically picks the lat, lng for your location

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/trending?ll=40.7,-74&oauth_token=[TOKEN]&v=20120325

and it return lot of results for the above url.

While using a third party service to get lat, lng for my ip address I get the coordinates as 40.7013,-73.7074, just little different from what foursquare got for me. Guess what, it returns no results when these co-ordinates are specified.

Any idea how to handle this?

Thanks,
Mandeep.

Comment: I see plenty of results at that lat/long: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D40.7013,-73.7074. BTW, these two places are pretty far away, (http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.7,-74.0&z=15 vs. http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=40.7013,-73.7074&z=11), I'm not surprised that they return different results.

Comment: Oh I see now you were asking about the `venues/trending` endpoint. I can confirm that no results are returned for that endpoint with that lat/long. I'm not sure why that would be, perhaps there's nothing trending at that location? It is further from a population center than the other lat/long location (further out on Long Island vs. in Brooklyn).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the api: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/trending

You can specify a radius up to about 2000 meters. That's not really very large...